# C++: Duda con arreglos dinamicos y llamadas a metodos de una clase

Tags: c++

estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con clases en c++ y me surge la siguiente duda:

¿Cual es la diferencia entre llamar a un metodo de esta forma `(coches+indice)->mostrarDatos();` como se ve en el archivo main y esta otra `coches[0].getPrecio()` como en el archivo Vehiculo.cpp?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehiculo.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Vehiculo* coches;
    int nro,indice;
    std::string marca,modelo;
    float precio;


    std::cout<<"Digite el numero de vehiculos: ";std::cin>>nro;

    coches = new Vehiculo[nro];

    std::cout<<"---- Pidiendo datos ----"<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    for(int i = 0;i<nro;i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        std::cout<<"Marca: ";getline(std::cin,marca);
        std::cout<<"Modelo: ";getline(std::cin,modelo);
        std::cout<<"Precio: ";std::cin>>precio;
        coches[i] = Vehiculo(marca,modelo,precio);
        system("cls");
    }
    indice = Vehiculo::Barato(coches,nro);
    std::cout<<"---- Vehiculo mas barato ----"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    (coches+indice)->mostrarDatos();

    return 0;
}
```

Vehiculo.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehiculo{
    private:
        std::string marca;
        std::string modelo;
        float precio;
    public:
        Vehiculo(std::string marca,std::string modelo,float precio){
            this->marca = marca;
            this->modelo = modelo;
            this->precio = precio;
        }
        Vehiculo(){}
        float getPrecio();
        void mostrarDatos();
        static int Barato(Vehiculo coches[],int n);
        ~Vehiculo(){

        }
};
```

Vehiculo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehiculo.h"

float Vehiculo::getPrecio(){
    return precio;
}
void Vehiculo::mostrarDatos(){
    std::cout<<"Marca: "<<marca<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Modelo: "<<modelo<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Precio: "<<precio<<std::endl<<std::endl;
}

int Vehiculo::Barato(Vehiculo coches[],int n){
    float precio = coches[0].getPrecio();
    int indice = 0;

    for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){
        if(precio > coches[0].getPrecio()){
            precio  = coches[i].getPrecio();
            indice = i;             
        }
    }
    return indice;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninguno de los dos casos tiene nada que ver con clases.

**aritmética de punteros**

```
(coches+indice)->mostrarDatos();
```

En este caso, `coches` es un array, es decir, una sucesión de elementos en memoria, de tal forma que `coches` se queda apuntando al primer elemento de la citada colección.

Pues bien, el compilador sabe que cada elemento ocupa `n` bytes, (puedes calcular `n` usando el operador `sizeof`), por lo que puede calcular exactamente que desplazamiento tiene que aplicar para acceder al elemento `indice`.

**operador de indexación**

```
coches[0].getPrecio()
```

No es sino otra forma en la que puedes acceder a los diferentes elementos de una colección.

Este operador tiene la peculiaridad respecto a la aritmética de punteros, en que es sobrecargable. Es decir, puedes crear objetos que incluyan su propia implementación del operador:

```
class POO
{
public:

    int operator[](int value)
    { std::cout << "operator[](" << value << ")\n"; return value; }
};
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fptPDTHIXwndBMDf)

Por otro lado, cuando el operador se aplica sobre un puntero la lógica resultante será la obtenida mediante aritmética de punteros, es decir, las siguientes línas son equivalentes:

```
coches[5].mostrarDatos();
(coches + 5)->mostrarDatos();
```

¿pero... por qué en un caso se usa el punto y en el otro hay que usar una flecha?

Básicamente porque con aritmética de punteros estamos trabajando con punteros. Y para acceder al contenido de un puntero hay que usar el operador de indirección (la flecha). Sin embargo, al usar el operador de indización nos da acceso directo al objeto de la posición  `n`,  y para acceder a propiedades de objetos usamos el operador punto.

Existe una tercera forma de acceder a los objetos de la colección. Podemos desreferenciar el puntero de forma explícita:

```
*(coches + 5).mostrarDatos();
```

En este caso, con el asterisco accedemos a la posición de memoria correspondiente al sexto elemento (recuerda que los índices empiezan en 0) y posteriormente usamos el operador punto para acceder a las propiedades del objeto alojado en esa posición de memoria.

Comment: Si sustituyo ```(coches + indice)->mostrarDatos();``` por ```coches[5]->mostrarDatos(); ``` no compila, en el segundo caso hay que cambiar el -> por un punto , por eso pregunto de si hay alguna diferencia entre una o la otra.

Comment: @Franco perdona, cometí una errata... lo corrijo en 5 minutos

Comment: Gracias, o sea que hacerlo de una u otra forma no me afecta el funcionamiento del programa en nada?

Comment: @Franco exacto. Es indiferente. Dependiendo de la situación, puedes elegir la forma que mejor se adapte a tu código